# How can i create a custom object with specific OwnerId

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am creating some salesforce custom objects by apex but this must be created with an specific OwnerId(not the one who runs the code). The problem is that I am not being able to edit OwnerId property

```
Answer__c.OwnerId = id
```

This code does not compile, How can I achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: There was a mistake, Answer__c is a detail object. It looks like It receive owner from master object!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the controlled by parent for the object in the sharing rules. I think that might fix this.